# I have some questions about the Xposed active invocation method

Tags: android, xposed-framework

I have written before the method is executed after the hook operation.

Now I want to trigger the hook method in my own interface.

How should I call the hook method

A short example code would be nice :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

You need to call [java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...))

**Long Answer**

I assume you want to call ("invoke") the method you hooked from some other parts of your code.

First you need access to the [Member](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Member.html) and the [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) you want to call the function on.

1. In your [beforeHookedMethod()](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.html#beforeHookedMethod(de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam)) or [afterHookedMethod()](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.html#afterHookedMethod(de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam)) you receive an object of the type [XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam.html)
2. This object has fields [method](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam.html#method) of type [Member](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Member.html) and [thisObject](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam.html#thisObject) of the type [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html). Save these variables for later.
3. Later, in your interface, when you want to call the function, simply cast the above Member as a [Method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and call [Method.invoke()](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) with the thisObject as Parameter.

**Code Example** -

```
//To save the returned Member and Object
public static Method myMember;
public static Object myObject;
.
.
.
//In your hook
protected Object beforeHookedMethod(MethodHookParam methodHookParam){
//Cast to method and save for later
    myMember = (Method) methodHookParam.method;
    myObject = methodHookParam.thisObject;
}
.
.
.
//Later, in your interface, to call the function
myMember.invoke(myObject)
```

*Note* - If you need to pass arguments to the function call, the MethodHookParam object you got in 1 also has those in the [args](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam.html#args) field.

**Easier - If the function you want to call is static**

If the function is static, you don't need to wait for the callback.

1. The functions you called to hook (such as [findAndHookMethod()](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedHelpers.html#findAndHookMethod(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...)))
   return an object of the type [XC_MethodHook.Unhook](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.Unhook.html) as the parameter.
2. Calling [getHookedMethod()](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.Unhook.html#getHookedMethod()) on that object will return and object
   of type [Member](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Member.html)
3. Simply cast this Member as a [Method](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) and call
   [Method.invoke(null)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) (The object can be null since the function is static.)

*Note* - Also, If you are still hooked to that method, your [beforeHookedMethod()](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.html#beforeHookedMethod(de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam)) and [afterHookedMethod()](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XC_MethodHook.html#afterHookedMethod(de.robv.android.xposed.XC_MethodHook.MethodHookParam)) will still be called when calling this function. If you dont want these to be called, use [XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethod()](http://api.xposed.info/reference/de/robv/android/xposed/XposedBridge.html#invokeOriginalMethod(java.lang.reflect.Member,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object[])) instead of Method.invoke() above.

Comment: Hello, @Akhil Kedia.
I've tried following your guide, but I can't get any successful results.
Please give me some hint.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77471263/how-to-call-hooked-method-using-xposed-framework-api